# How can I change the alignment of bar columns in highchart in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graph, highcharts, jqbargraph

Wanted to change the alignment of bar graph to the center
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to disable `grouping` for your series:

```
  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      grouping: false
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wz3cjmfn/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.grouping